# Kubernetes: After building a cluster through Flannel network components, nodes cannot access each other through Flanner network segments

Tags: kubernetes, containers

After Kubernetes built a cluster through the Flannel network component, they were unable to access each other through the Flannel network segment, and the master node ping 10.244.2.0 (node1 node Flannel network segment) timed out.

kubernetes version 1.24.2

master Flannel Virtual Network Card Information

```
[root@master1 k8s]#  ifconfig flannel.1
flannel.1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:94:4B:2E:EA:5D  
          inet addr:10.244.0.0  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::5494:4bff:fe2e:ea5d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:988 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:58486 (57.1 KiB)
```

The request logs captured by tcpdump are as follows

```
[root@master1 k8s]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 30000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:47:33.186133 IP 172.16.29.34.60629 > master1.ndmps: Flags [S], seq 902841225, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:33.203308 IP 172.16.29.34.60630 > master1.ndmps: Flags [S], seq 2938533821, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:33.438264 IP 172.16.29.34.60633 > master1.ndmps: Flags [S], seq 2972658478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:34.200834 IP 172.16.29.34.60629 > master1.ndmps: Flags [S], seq 902841225, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:34.215896 IP 172.16.29.34.60630 > master1.ndmps: Flags [S], seq 2938533821, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:34.447110 IP 172.16.29.34.60633 > master1.ndmps: Flags [S], seq 2972658478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:36.214314 IP 172.16.29.34.60629 > master1.ndmps: Flags [S], seq 902841225, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

```
[root@master1 ~]# tcpdump -i flannel.1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on flannel.1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:47:33.186218 IP master1.63168 > 10.244.2.3.pcsync-https: Flags [S], seq 902841225, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:33.203355 IP master1.47411 > 10.244.2.3.pcsync-https: Flags [S], seq 2938533821, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:33.438341 IP master1.37028 > 10.244.2.3.pcsync-https: Flags [S], seq 2972658478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:34.200885 IP master1.63168 > 10.244.2.3.pcsync-https: Flags [S], seq 902841225, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:34.215930 IP master1.47411 > 10.244.2.3.pcsync-https: Flags [S], seq 2938533821, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:47:34.447159 IP master1.37028 > 10.244.2.3.pcsync-https: Flags [S], seq 2972658478, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

Routing Information

```
[root@master1 k8s]# ip route
default via 172.16.103.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
10.244.1.0/24 via 10.244.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
172.16.103.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.103.66 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
```

ARP and bridge information

```
[root@master1 k8s]# arp -n
? (10.244.2.0) at 3e:18:6e:82:70:79 [ether] PERM on flannel.1
? (172.16.103.253) at 08:4f:0a:70:6d:99 [ether]  on eth0
? (172.16.103.251) at 14:96:2d:4d:3d:0f [ether]  on eth0
? (10.244.1.0) at 0a:31:9f:e4:b3:14 [ether] PERM on flannel.1
? (172.16.103.68) at fe:fc:fe:ff:13:65 [ether]  on eth0
? (172.16.103.67) at fe:fc:fe:ff:ee:0c [ether]  on eth0
? (172.16.103.254) at 34:00:a3:3f:26:f9 [ether]  on eth0
[root@master1 k8s]# bridge  fdb | grep 3e:18:6e:82:70:79
3e:18:6e:82:70:79 dev flannel.1 dst 172.16.103.67 self permanent
```

And the master node can access the real IP address of the node node (172.16.103.67) (which should rule out security group and firewall issues), No error messages for kube channel, kube proxy, and coredns。

How should we solve or find the cause